# Internal Server Error in MongoDB Data Retrieval based on a variable saved in Local Storage

Tags: javascript, html

in my local storage I have saved an idCode variable. I want to use this code to retrive information from my mongodb database and show some information in my html page, but I'm not able to access it in my controller page.
this is my controller file code:

controller/results.js

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const result = require("../models/result");


exports.getResultPage = async (req, res) => {
    try {
    const idCode = "5558"

    const result = await result.find({ code: idCode });

    const data = result.find(item => item.block === 2);

      // Render the view and pass the result and meanTimeDifference
    res.render("result/result", { result, data });
    } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).send("Internal Server Error");
    }
};
```

routes/result.js

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const resultController = require("../controllers/results");

router.get("/", resultController.getResultPage);

module.exports = router;
```

javascript file

```
const idCode = localStorage.getItem("idCode");
```

and this is my view file:

```
<h3>Results</h3>
<p>Data: <%= data %></p>
```

I'm getting an Internal Server Error error since I'm not able to get the right idCode. If i manually put an idCode that exists in my databse the code actually works.
How can I fix this?

Comment: the code you posted doesn't show where you're trying to retrieve `idCode` from localStorage.

Comment: I have added also my javascript file code where i'm trying to get the idCode from the local storage, I don't know how to "pass" it to the controller file